# Generic method in Scala GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

object Test {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val graph = GraphGenerator.generate_graph()
   println(graph.numEdges)
   println(solve(graph))
 }

 def solve[A,B](graph: Graph[A,B]) = {
   graph.numEdges
 }
}
```

Why does graph.numEdges work correctly in main function and doesn't in solve?

Compiler output: numEdges is not a member of Graph[A, B].

If I change graph.numEdges to graph.edges.count() it works.

Answer (score 3):

`GraphOps` methods require `ClassTag` to address type erasure.  You can define your function as:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def solve[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag](graph: Graph[A, B]) = graph.numEdges
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens if `Graph[A,B]` does not have `val numEdges` while the actual class behind `graph` does.

Edit: The `val numEdges` comes from `GraphOps`:

`class GraphOps[VD: ClassTag, ED: ClassTag](graph: Graph[VD, ED]) extends Serializable {
  /** The number of edges in the graph. */
  @transient lazy val numEdges: Long = graph.edges.count()`

Which `Graph` gets implicitly:

`abstract class Graph[VD: ClassTag, ED: ClassTag] protected () extends Serializable {
...
  implicit def graphToGraphOps[VD: ClassTag, ED: ClassTag]
      (g: Graph[VD, ED]): GraphOps[VD, ED] = g.ops`

But only when VD and ED (in our case A, B) are `scala.reflect.ClassTag`s - and your solve function does not require that, thus the implicit conversion does not take place.